# What does "a member template of a class" refer to in the C++ standard?

Tags: c++, templates

The C++ standard states:

> A template defines a family of classes or functions.
>
> ```
> template-declaration:
>    exportopt template < template-parameter-list > declaration
> ```
>
> The declaration in a template-declaration shall
>
> - declare or define a function or a class, or
> - define a member function, a member class or a static data member of a class template or of a class nested within a class template, or
> - define a member template of a class or class template.

The third of these bullet points is what is confusing me. What is an example of "a member template of a class" in this context? A member function or nested class definition would be included in one of the first two categories. Surely there's no such thing as a templatised data member? Is this referring to typedefs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A member template of a class is a member function that is itself a template, like these:

```
class test {
   template <typename T> void foo(); // member template of class
};
template <typename T>
void test::foo<T>() {}               // definition

template <typename T>
class test2 {
   template <typename U> void foo(); // member template of class template
};
template <typename T>
template <typename U>
void test2<T>::foo<U>() {}           // definition
```

Comment: I see. I was assuming that would fit into the category of "member function ... of a class template".